# GCD global queue task run on main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

The following code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print(Thread.current)
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        print(Thread.current)
    }
}
```

prints

```
<_NSMainThread: 0x60000059c140>{number = 1, name = main}
<_NSMainThread: 0x60000059c140>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Technically, global queue finds an idle thread to run the task, which might be the main thread.

Is there any explicit rule indicates when a task added to global queue will be performed on main thread?

So time consuming tasks put in the global queue wouldn't affect the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> Technically, global queue finds an idle thread to run the task, which might be the main thread.

Generally global queue selects a thread of the appropriate quality of service from the pool of worker threads. When grabbing a worker thread, it is not the case that it might just randomly grab the main thread. It only selects from its pool of worker threads.

What you are seeing here is a very specific optimization for *synchronous* calls (but not *asynchronous* calls). As the `sync` [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync):

> As a performance optimization, [`sync`] executes blocks on the current thread whenever possible, ...

This optimization is possible with synchronous calls because the current thread will be blocked during a synchronous dispatch, anyways. So GCD can avoid the costly context switch that is not needed/desired. It's a clever little optimization.

So, when will the aforementioned performance optimization not be employed? The above [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync) quote continues:

> ... with one exception: Blocks submitted to the main dispatch queue always run on the main thread.

So, if you do the converse of your example (i.e., dispatch synchronously from a background queue to the main queue, or any queue that uses the main queue as its ultimate “target”), the optimization is turned off and it will do the context switch to the main thread, regardless. It has to do that because there are certain API calls and the like which must happen on the main thread, so the optimization is disabled in this scenario.

There are other, less well documented, scenarios where this optimization may not be employed. One would be well advised to not overly rely on this optimization. Just rest assured that when GCD can, it will attempt to avoid costly context switches for synchronously dispatched tasks.

Answer (score 0):

A sync task will block your calling thread, which is the main thread in your code.

Even if the task in the global queue is dispatched to a global thread rather than the main thread. The main thread still needs to wait for the task to be completed.

In this case, GCD automatically optimizes the sync dispatch so that the task to be executed on the calling thread rather than let the calling thread waiting.